# CentOS 7 MongoDB EXT4 to XFS filesystem

Tags: mongodb, centos, filesystems, xfs

When I start the MongoDB console, it shows the following warning:
[Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXIwl.png)

When I run "df -Th" it shows the following: [Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jpEAW.png)

Is it possible to change the filesystem of my CentOS, without reinstalling it?

Thank you :)

Comment: This question really belongs on [dba.stackexchange.com](https://dba.stackexchange.com) which is the site to use for database administration and configuration questions. StackOverflow is for programming topics only, of which this question is not. **Please move your question to the correct site by deleting and reposting.**